# Should I delete the answer where OP gives own answer from my logic?

Tags: discussion, support

I had answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927092/accept-two-radio-selections-with-the-same-name/33931093#33931093). The owner of the question understood my answer properly and then they applied the given logic and answered their [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927092/accept-two-radio-selections-with-the-same-name/33931093#33931093).

Now, should I delete my answer? Or keep it there in case it helps someone else?

Comment: Their answer has no explanation that accompanies the code.  Don't delete your answer.

Comment: I was in a similar condition here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904941/find-employees-whose-supervisors-supervisor-is-a-specific-person/32905243#32905243. But I didn't delete the answer. Not because I have a strong moral fiber, because I was being a rep-wh**e xD

Comment: Kevin does have a point with his comment in the self-answer. You basically posted a meme and now an answer here, with good intentions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492 . Don't delete the answer, but be aware that providing JQuery answers where JQuery is not asked is not really the way to go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not delete it. First, it is upvoted,which is a sign that somebody found helpful or nicely written. And above all it gives some textual explaination what is lacking from OP's answer.

IMHO the good question here is (apart from own rep :-) ) *does it add information?*. The answer is yes so keep it.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not delete it. Your answer provides additional content, additional context and explaination. To be fair from what I read the OP copy pasted your answer largely and then accepted his answer. On first glance this sounds awfully suspicious of an OP trying to score some more free points off *your* answer. If anything he should have accepted your answer instead.

Comment: OP won't earn any rep by self answering and accepting his own answer. Using another answer as a base and improving it or adding the full  working code in a self answer is perfectly acceptable. But I agree with you in that particular case OP should have accepted the other answer (since it was the one that helped most) **and** added his code in another answer if he thought it useful for future readers.

Comment: @SergeBallesta If I wanted to assume malicious intent I would say that by accepting his own answer it would rise to the top and contain (correct) code, and would be likely to attract upvotes. That could be a reason why he did it.

Comment: @Magisch I'm not certain, but I believe that self-answers don't rise to the top like normal accepted answers do.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: They don't, presumably for exactly this reason. They're always sorted by the usual sort order, without regard for the accepted mark.

Comment: If I wanted to assume malicious intent, I would say that many relatively new users, like this one, wouldn't know that accepting their own answer gives them no reputation points.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes But if the competing answer was selected then that answer would stay at the top, and the self answer could never get above it.  The accept mark also draws the eye, increasing the odds that it gets read over accepting the other answer.

Comment: @Servy Fair point. Still, the lack of floaty-upness does help mitigate the effect.